# How to create a pop-up bubble (tooltip)

Tags: tooltip, qualtrics

In Qualtrics, how can I insert a pop-up bubble (tooltip) onto a page so that respondents can swipe over the bubble and see additional information?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up a hover over tooltip within your survey.

Editing in the source mode, add this code to where you want your tooltip to show up.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tip">Text to response to pop-up<span>
This is the text that will display in the tooltip pop-up.</span></a>
```

To make the tooltip react, add the CSS code below to your survey. In Qualtric, go to **'Look & Feel' > 'Advanced' > '+ Custom CSS'** and add the following CSS code:

```
/* Tooltip container */
.tip{
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
cursor: help; /*change the cursor symbol to a question mark on mouse over*/
color: inherit; /*inherit text color*/
text-decoration: none; /*remove underline*/
}

/*Tooltip text*/
.tip .tipText{
visibility: hidden;
width:28em;
text-align: left;
padding: .6em;
padding-left: 1em;
border: 1px solid [template("base font color")]'
border-radius: 0.5em;
font: 400 12px Arial;
color: #fff; /*white*/
background-color: #404040; /*grey*/
display: inline-block;

/*Position the tooltip text*/
position: absolute; /*positioned relative to the tooltip container*/
top: -5px;
left: 105%;
z-index: 100;
}
```

My answer is heavily adapted from SurveyGizmo's [documentation page](https://help.surveygizmo.com/help/hover-text), but I have found a way to make it work for my survey in Qualtrics.

You can customise the colour and font of your text, pop-up bubble background, and border by editing the CSS code.

Answer (score 1):

To get it to work right I needed to add hover CSS and I used span rather than a specific class call.

```
   /* Tooltip container */
.tip{
position: relative; 
display: inline-block;
cursor: help; /*change the cursor symbol to a question mark on mouse over*/
color: red; 
float: right;
font-style: bold;
text-decoration: none; /*remove underline*/
}

/*Tooltip text*/
.tip span {
visibility: hidden;
width:80%;
text-align: left;
padding: .6em;
padding-left: 1em;
border: 1px solid [template("base font color")]'
border-radius: 0.5em;
font: 400 12px Arial;
color: #fff; 
background-color: #404040; 
display: inline-block;

/*Position the tooltip text*/
position: fixed; 
bottom: 20px;
left: 10%;
z-index: 100;
}

.tip:hover span {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is called a tooltip, a simple way is to add a title to the div containing the element. Similar to this:

```html
<div title="This is additional Information">Here is text, hover over me for more information.</div>
```

There are "fancier" ways of doing this, but many people have spent time perfecting these methods, so I would recommend using some tooltip library if you want to do this in a fancier way.